# CKeditor custom builder "hasFocus" error

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to make a custom build of CKeditor. I am taking the full editor, removing some plugins and adding placeholder.
When putting it in my page I get:

```
 ckeditor.js:731 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasFocus' of undefined
  at $.showBlock (ckeditor.js:731)
  at Object.execute (ckeditor.js:799)
  at $.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:799)
  at ckeditor.js:31
  at Object.callFunction (ckeditor.js:31)
```

My config file is empty - to make sure I am not adding errors.
I call the editor with:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'etiq_template', {});
```

Of course, If I use the prebuilt full editor, it perfectly works, even when in my config I put:

```
config.removeButtons = 'Save,Form,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,Flash,Smiley,Iframe,Image';
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong ? I really would like to have the placeholder widget - but if I can't I will program something less fancy to replace it.

thanks for any idea and pointer

Comment: I would recommend that you go to online builder page http://ckeditor.com/builder, clear your browser's cache according to http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache, reload the page and try building your editor custom there.
The advantage of the builder is that if you add a plugin like placeholder, it will also add all the other plugins required by that particular plugin. If you are doing this manually you must manage plugin dependencies on your own.
If the builder is not a solution for you, please explain in more detail, how are you building your custom editor.

Comment: Thanks but that is what I did. I went to the builder and built my custom editor there. It is because that version was not working that I downloaded the full version to make sure the problem was not in my code. The full version works. But I cannot make any custom build editor working.  I will change browser to make sure there is nothing in the cache and try again.

Comment: I was using Safari and Firefox. I changed browser to Chrome, and now it works. I also did it differently. Instead of selecting full and removing plugins, I chose standard and added plugins. And now it works. Don't know if it is a browser problem or if it is better to add than remove. But it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have it working now. I am not sure why, but this is what I did.
First I change browser to Chrome - I was using Safari and Firefox.

Second (and maybe this is the most important) I started from the standard editor and added the plugins I wanted, instead of starting from full editor and removing plugins.

It now works perfectly